# Using graph api to bulk upload to facebook company page (not a user page)

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, upload

I found [this,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2780278/can-i-upload-photos-to-a-wall-belonging-to-a-fan-company-page-wall-using-the-f) but it is kinda confusing, and doesn't answer the question for me. I'm looking to upload images from my website to a Facebook page (my code works for users pages, not company pages), if there is a way to do it without having to make an application, I'd like that, but from what I've seen, that's not possible.

My code is here: http://pastebin.com/wBp1AQwG

Answer (score 0):

Your link doesn't appear to go anywhere useful, I'm afraid.

Nonetheless, I'm guessing your problem here is that you need to use a Page access token not a user access token to publish to a page rather than a user feed.

See the section on Page Access Tokens at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

Comment: I've already figured it out, I'll outline my process, but I won't give code.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, here is a basic outline of the process for posting an image to an album that you own on a fanpage.

1. Get user authenticated
2. Get users accounts
3. Get albums, or create them
4. Post to the id of the album (ALBUM_ID/photos) with the image

It's pretty simple once I figured out the basics of the api.